# NULL if have just one line in R

Tags: r, loops, syntax, null

I am trying to transform a dataframe `Neigh` = `NULL` if it has just one line:

I have tried:

```
Neigh <- Neigh[-(which(sapply(Neigh,nrow == 1)))]
```

I have one loop to plot graphs, but I don´t want to plot those with just one line. That's why I am trying to make the dataframes with one line = `NULL`.

Comment: Why don't you simply use an `if` condition in your loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roland just said, you can use an `if` condition. Use it with the `nrow` function (which returns the number of rows of your data.frame object) and you are done.

A simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(1,letters[1])
if(nrow(df)==1) {
  df <- NULL
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I had forgotten to rename my data.frame. It's edited !